# What is new in Google Gin 1.5?

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin

Has anyone tried the recently released version of [Google Gin (1.5)](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/)? I would like to know the new features in the release and any usage experiences with GWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This release brings some major new features to Gin, such as AsyncProviders, 
AssistedInject and JSR330 compatibility. There are also plenty of bug fixes 
and better error reporting included.

As previously discussed, this release contains two compiled and source 
versions, one for use with GWT 2.2.1 and before and one for GWT 2.2.0 and 
later.

(c)  Peter Schmitt [groups google - Gin 1.5 released](http://groups.google.com/group/google-gin/browse_frm/thread/ac3b32e0f70d1bcc)

Comment: Thanks Helpa!. I wish they had that bit on their main project page (or a release note).

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective the main difference was compatibility with GWT 2.2. GIN 1.0 doesn't work with GWT 2.2.